# The maven web project runs error in eclipse(tomcat 7):error:Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I use tomcat7,eclipse 4.6.2 and my own maven 3(not the default in eclipse).

here is my tomcat_users.xml:

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script" />
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager,manager-script,admin-gui" />
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui" />
```

here is my settings.xml in maven 3:

E:\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml

```
<server> 
       <id>tomcat7</id> 
       <username>admin</username> 
       <password>admin</password> 
</server>
```

the local repository is at C:\Users\zhuxiaodong.m2\repository

I create a maven web project called "webapp"
and the part of my pom.xml is:

```
<build>  
       <finalName>webapp</finalName>  
       <plugins>  
            <!-- Eclipse project -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8425/manager/text</url>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                    <server>tomcat7</server>
                    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
       </plugins>  
   </build>
   <repositories>
        <repository> 
            <id>people.apache.snapshots</id> 
            <url> 
                http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/ 
            </url> 
            <releases> 
                <enabled>false</enabled> 
            </releases> 
            <snapshots> 
                <enabled>true</enabled> 
            </snapshots> 
        </repository> 
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository> 
            <id>apache.snapshots</id> 
            <name>Apache Snapshots</name> 
            <url> 
                http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/ 
            </url> 
            <releases> 
                <enabled>false</enabled> 
            </releases> 
            <snapshots> 
                <enabled>true</enabled> 
            </snapshots> 
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrRrD.png)
And I run the project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Software caused connection abort: socket write error -> [Help 1]

    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

what's wrong? thank you!
if the information is not complete,l will show more details.
(the project is for testing spring mvc and spring security)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the below bock in Tomcat's `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

And change the port to `8080` instead of `8425` in your `pom.xml`

Comment: the problem is in tomcat_users.xml.   l add the manager-jmx config to admin.  and l success